# Word for "being overly protective of petty things"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (noun, verb, adjective -- I don't care which) that describes the quality of being overly defensive of little things?

For example...

---

Dave: God, Alicia gets hostile when I ask for a little piece of candy, and she guards her stash of pencils like a bulldog.

Jane: Yeah, and she has so much candy and so many pencils anyways!

Dave: She really is ___________.

---

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two words come to mind. The first is "overprotective":

> Unduly protective

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overprotective?s=t)

You could also go with "possessive":

> desirous of possessing, especially excessively so

[Dictionary.com](http://desirous%20of%20possessing,%20especially%20excessively%20so)

Both of these can fit your idea, but it's quite a specific idea for a single describing word. Sometimes you can't really cram too many ideas into one word and must rely on context or describing words, such as adjectives and adverbs.

Answer (score 0):

I think **possessive** is the right term.

> unwilling to let other people use something you own
>
> *He’s so possessive about his new car.*
>
> *Alice is very possessive about her pencils.*

(Longman)

Answer (score 0):

She is just "[***stingy***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stingy)":

> not generous or liberal :  ***sparing or scant in*** using,
>   ***giving,*** or spending

[Merriam-Webster]